# Rotate only view and not its subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is there any way by which transform of a view for rotation wont be passed to its subviews?
I have a custom MKAnnotationView which I am rotating according to the heading values of the user. In below method in the custom Annotation view class , i am adding a subview to the annotation view.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if(selected)
{
  [self addSubview:self.myCallOutView];
  return;
}
  [self.myCallOutView removeFromSuperview];


}
```

but the problem is when my annotation view is rotated and then I select any annotation, myCallOutView also appears rotated which I dont want. I am rotating custom Annotation view using below line

```
  [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * M_PI / -180.0)];
```

How can i avoid this situation? Do i need to apply some transform on myCallOutView before adding it as a subview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One very simple solution would be to perform the reverse rotation on the subview:

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * M_PI / -180.0)];
// NOTE: we're using the negative of the angle here
[self.myCallOutView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- angle * M_PI / -180.0)]];
```

This will cancel out the effect of the rotation on the superview.

**Alternative approach:** structure your views a little differently: instead of having view A inside view B, have both views A and B being subviews of a container view C. Then just apply your rotation to view A, B won't be affected. And to move the whole ensemble on the display, relocate the container view C.

Comment: yes ok i will try it and i think it will work..Btw you need to apply some transform to your profile pic.. :p

Comment: for people facing the same issue, I solved by using the Alternative approach mentioned in the above answer by occulus, as performing the reverse rotation on subview wont rotate the subview but its frame will get affected. Go for second approach

Comment: Hi Occulus , above code is working fine, subview component size is getting change. how to solve that issue

Comment: @KavithaMadhu For the best chance of getting help with that, post a new question with example code.