# How to make some view not to rotate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have some viewcontroller.

I need to rotate all it's subview's except one.

Is it possible? Should i use apply `CGAffineTransformMakeRotate` to this one to keep it not rotatable?

Or can i implement such a viewcontrollers to add one on another in such way that parent do not react on rotation and child reacts?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question:

[Rotate only view and not its subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546510/rotate-only-view-and-not-its-subviews/15546561#15546561)

It's pretty much the same question. Either of my approaches would work in theory.

Comment: It's really nice, i thought MakeRotate as you see in the question. But it is not some button for example to rotate in simple. The content is really heavy, so i wat not to use affine transforms. May be it is possible to overlay to viewcontrollers, and make one rotate and other no.

Comment: @occulus you have a very appropriate picture for this question :)